# Gray background when switching workspaces

Tags: workspace, dconf, bugs

I wanted to swap workspaces on second screen with this command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary true`

After some tests, I decided to reset the setting:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false`

And now when I switch workspaces, the background becomes gray for a second ([see video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkXRW.jpg)).

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears when the main screen is on the right side. Switching main window to the left side is now working properly. To achive this we have 2 options:

1. Settings -> Display -> Star icon on left screen
   [image]
2. or use terminal and add `--primary` tag to specific monitor `$ xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --scale 1.33x1.33 --primary  --output DisplayPort-1 --pos 2554x0`